# Deleting a line from a file

Tags: java

Please help to solve this problem.
I want to delete every line from a file after reading that line. Can we delete like this?
I don't want use any temporary file to do this process.

please help me, thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to delete the lines? Only if your file is 50000+ lines will it affect your speed much. When reading it it goes through each line. Read it into a string array and then delete the file or clear it in total. Read the remaining/wanted lines back if needed.

Comment: Your request is impossible. Take a sheet of paper, draw some lines on it. Now imagine this is a "file" on disk. If you "delete" the first line on your paper, what do you wish to happen? Do you want all the other lines at the same place on paper? So what should "replace" the deleted line? Or do you want to move the other lines to the top of your sheet? Then you have to read them and to write them there! Exactly as you can not simply let a part of your paper sheet vanish you also can not delete a part inside of a file.

Comment: Guys it seems like he is asking for a truncation "from after reading that line". Even if you didn't truncate it's possible (by first finding the line, and then copying bytes backwards, and then truncating the file according to the length of the search line).

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this without a temporary file, unless it's the last line. You could *overwrite* the line of text (although that's not as easy as you might think unless the lines are a fixed size) - if there's some way you could indicate to whatever's reading the file that a line should be ignored, that's an option. But you can't reduce the file size by removing data from the middle of it. It's simply not an operation that most file systems support.

Likewise you can't insert extra information in the middle of a file. Basically the available operations are overwriting, appending and truncating.

Comment: I do believe that some operating systems can truncate a file.  It is not part of standard Java runtime, though.

Comment: @Thorbjørn: That's why I included the "most" in "not an operation that most file systems support" :)

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do it. Thought it would be a challenge and a good test of `System.Text.Encoding` ninjitsu. Here you go:

```
static bool DeleteEveryLineAfter(Stream data, string search, Encoding encoding)
{
    const int WindowsPageSize = 4096;

    var decoder = encoding.GetDecoder();
    var encoder = encoding.GetEncoder();

    var buffer = new byte[WindowsPageSize];
    var length = 0;
    var searchPosition = 0;

    var newLine = Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray();
    var newLinePosition = 0;
    var currentLinePosition = 0;
    var lineIsValid = true;

    while ((length = data.Read(buffer, 0, WindowsPageSize)) != 0)
    {
        // Get the characters.
        var chars = new char[decoder.GetCharCount(buffer, 0, length, false)];
        decoder.GetChars(buffer, 0, length, chars, 0, false);

        for (var i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
        {
            var c = chars[i];

            if (
                // Only if the line isn't LONGER than what we are searching for.
                searchPosition < search.Length &&
                // And if the current character matches.
                search[searchPosition] == c &&
                // And we have matched something in it, or it is the start of the line.
                (searchPosition > 0 || currentLinePosition == 0) &&
                // And if a previous character didn't fail.
                lineIsValid
                )
            {
                searchPosition++;
                newLinePosition = 0;
            }
            else if (newLinePosition < newLine.Length && c == newLine[newLinePosition])
            {
                newLinePosition++;
                // Did we match the whole newline.
                if (newLinePosition == newLine.Length)
                {
                    // Was the current line a match?
                    if (lineIsValid && searchPosition == search.Length)
                    {
                        // Figure out the different between the amount of data
                        // we read, and how long the line was.
                        var bytesLeft = encoder.GetByteCount(chars, i, chars.Length - i, true);
                        var finalLength = data.Position - bytesLeft;
                        data.SetLength(finalLength);
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lineIsValid = true;
                        newLinePosition = 0;
                        searchPosition = 0;
                        currentLinePosition = -1; // Compensate for ++ below.
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lineIsValid = false;
            }

            currentLinePosition++;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Oh, it's tagged Java. Haha, well there is the C# for you. Translation to Java left as an excersise for the student.